# 0x19 blue screen randomly appearing while installing or looking for updates

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod

I keep getting random Blue Screen for this error: 0x19 while installing or looking for updates in windows update tool, here is the WinDbg result:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

BAD_POOL_HEADER (19)
The pool is already corrupt at the time of the current request.
This may or may not be due to the caller.
The internal pool links must be walked to figure out a possible cause of
the problem, and then special pool applied to the suspect tags or the driver
verifier to a suspect driver.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000020, a pool block header size is corrupt.
Arg2: fffff8a0034f64a0, The pool entry we were looking for within the page.
Arg3: fffff8a0034f6990, The next pool entry.
Arg4: 00000000054f64a0, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x19_20

POOL_ADDRESS:  fffff8a0034f64a0 Paged pool

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002bb46d3 to fffff80002a82f00

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`06214a98 fffff800`02bb46d3 : 00000000`00000019 00000000`00000020 fffff8a0`034f64a0 fffff8a0`034f6990 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`06214aa0 fffff880`012b91b0 : fffff8a0`034f64b0 fffff880`086ec490 fffff880`4146744e fffffa80`0b5ceb40 : nt!ExFreePool+0xda4
fffff880`06214b50 fffff880`01220c0d : fffffa80`0b5ceb40 fffffa80`0b012350 fffff880`086ec490 fffffa80`084a3b00 : Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreate+0x22f9
fffff880`06214d30 fffff800`02a7ad87 : fffff880`086ec400 00000000`00000000 000007fe`ed7b0000 00000000`22923678 : Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreateCallout+0x1d
fffff880`06214d60 fffff800`02a7ad41 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxSwitchKernelStackCallout+0x27
fffff880`086ec2d0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSwitchKernelStackContinue


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreate+22f9
fffff880`012b91b0 e9bffcffff      jmp     Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreate+0x1fbd (fffff880`012b8e74)

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreate+22f9

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Ntfs

IMAGE_NAME:  Ntfs.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bc14f

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7600.16385

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x19_20_Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreate+22f9

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x19_20_Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreate+22f9

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x19_20_ntfs!ntfscommoncreate+22f9

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {940fe9b9-834f-128f-bc9e-9616e6aa37f8}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

2: kd> lmvm Ntfs
start             end                 module name
fffff880`0120f000 fffff880`013b2000   Ntfs       (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ntfs.pdb\A3FA3C11632A4FC09223AB611D6EFF7F2\ntfs.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: Ntfs.sys
    Mapped memory image file: c:\symbols\Ntfs.sys\4A5BC14F1a3000\Ntfs.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Ntfs.sys
    Image name: Ntfs.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 23:20:47 2009 (4A5BC14F)
    CheckSum:         00195F88
    ImageSize:        001A3000
    File version:     6.1.7600.16385
    Product version:  6.1.7600.16385
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        3.7 Driver
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntfs.sys
    OriginalFilename: ntfs.sys
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7600.16385
    FileVersion:      6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
    FileDescription:  NT File System Driver
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

here is a [link](http://sdrv.ms/1a2FuG6) to the dump.

my system is as following: **2x4 GB of RAM**/**Windows 7 Ultimate x64**/**Intel HD Graphics**

Comment: You have a driver conflict.  I would start to uninstall device drivers untill the crash doesn't happen.

Comment: Install the Win7 Sp1 and run chkdsk to check the HDD

Comment: @Ramhound the BSOD happens randomly, and sometimes with different error code, how should i know which one is the one causing the problem ?
[AT]magicandre1981 im on it.

Comment: @Omarrrio - I would use a process of elmination.  You need to use a program like BlueScreenViewer to get every driver file that was loaded, you can then guess, based on that data what devices were to blame.

Comment: @ramhound +1, thanks, i never thought i could get what drivers were loaded using BSV, i thought it was only to show the BSOD from the DUMP.

Comment: @Omarrrio - Well...it actuall does the `.dmp` contains all that information. Its basically a complete dump of the system state, and most of the time, it will indicate what file was in an erroed state.  Its the reason I was able to determine a infrequent issue was because of my video card driver.

Comment: @Ramhound so i should pretty much ignore all Microsoft related Drivers, right ?

Comment: have you done the chkdsk?

Comment: i cannot delete my previous comment, and i can no longer edit it, but [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gm30vBph) you go, here is the chckdsk results, it's in french, but it clearly says that it found no problem.